# ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels while using assign

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split the values inside the `engine_type` column using `_` delimiter using the following code

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/used_cars.csv")
dds = df.assign(engines_type= lambda x: x['engine_type'].str.split(r'\s*_\s*').explode()).reset_index()
```

I am getting the following error

> ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

What could be the reason for this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you explode, the length wouldn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```py
# Say you have a df like:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'car_model': ['Renualt', 'Hyundai', 'Ford'],
    'engine_type': ['Gas', 'Diesel_Petrol', 'Gas_Hybrid']
})

dds = (df.assign(engine_type=df['engine_type'].str.split(r'\s*_\s*'))
         .explode('engine_type')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
print(dds)
```

---

```
  car_model engine_type
0   Renualt         Gas
1   Hyundai      Diesel
2   Hyundai      Petrol
3      Ford         Gas
4      Ford      Hybrid
```

**Note:** If this doesn't help, you should provide a sample dataframe and a desired output.